# SharePoint/SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a criteria set that has a task process that emails a SharePoint user group.  However in this criteria I also want a criteria that if an item is assigned to a specific user of a SharePoint group it emails a single person. Is there anyway to incorporate that in the WF?  I already have a task setup but don't feel I need to recreate the task just to assign it to a different person based on the criteria.  I hope I am making sense. Fairly new to SharePoint!!

Comment: Are you using a person field to check if the item is assigned to a specific user?

Answer (score -2):

Put that email process in an IF statement for Assigned to = blank

Edit: In regards to comments below, I understood the question to be a workflow created in SPD.  As the user was new to SharePoint, I recommended putting an ElseIf branch around the workflow process.  NO CODE

Comment: Think this is a valid answer, albeit not a very helpful one - perhaps a code sample could be added.@Waqas, if you don't think it is good please just down-vote rather than flag for deletion. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the first comment may be in retaliation to an edit of an answer posted here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190498/least-privileged-administration-in-sharepoint-2013/190499#190499